# Programmatically login a Python web crawler

Tags: python, authentication, web-crawler, beautifulsoup

I am trying to make a web crawler that will login to a school website using my credentials and then crawl certain parts of the site. I am using the Beautiful Soup Python library found here:

```
http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/
```

I can get the correct source code for the username and password fields, but I do not know how to supply them. Also, I have the same problem with submitting them. I have the source code for the "Submit" button scraped but I do not know how to request to login.

Thanks,

Comment: mechanize might be a better choice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either use [Mechanize](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize/), a library that emulates a browser, or just send the POST/GET request manually.

[Mechanize's homepage](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/#examples) has a full example that you can try out.

If you want to go with the manual request, I usually just open Chrome's JS console, serialize the form and see which parameters get sent:

```
> $('form#search').serialize()
"q="
```

Then, you just send a `POST` request to that URL with those parameters:

```
import requests  # Install `requests` if you want to use my example code

session = requests.session()  # So your cookies persist across requests
response = session.post('your_url', data={
    'q': 'search string'
}).text
```

Comment: Thank you! Both look like great options but I will look into Mechanize